# Как настроить Автозагрузку пользователя в Windows 10 Аналогичную таковой в Windows Server?

Tags: windows-10, автозагрузка

В Серверной версии винды программы в авто запуске пользователя загружаются при загрузке системы, еще до того как пользователь Введет учетные данные или подключится.
Юзаю десятку как Терминальный сервер, надо загружать программы у администратора и при этом оставить компьютер заблокированным

Answer (score 1):

Нашел!!! Спустя несколько часов гугления причем нашел тут-же....
nеt usеr Пользователь /active:yes